# Variance of white noise and the STFT

Tags: noise, speech-processing, stft

I hope someone can help me understand the meaning of variance in this case. I am reading an old research paper by Ephraim and Malah (for my DSP project) and it says:

[image]

Knowing that $D_k$ is the FFT of white noise, what I am trying to find out is $\lambda_d(k)$. Can anyone explain to me the meaning of $E\lbrace|D_k|^2\rbrace$? I think it is the variance of a particular $D_k$ with respect to the mean, but since this is white noise, shouldn't it be zero?

Please help, I am stuck!!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E\{|D_k|^2\}$ is the expected value of the squared magnitude of the noise in the $k^{th}$ frequency bin. Since they assume that the noise is zero mean, this equals the noise variance. Remember that the variance of a random variable $X$ is defined as $\sigma_X^2=E\{|X-\mu_X|^2\}$, where $\mu_X=E\{X\}$ is the mean of $X$. So if $\mu_X=0$ (as assumed here for the noise) then $\sigma^2_X=E\{|X|^2\}$. Note that $E\{|D_k|^2\}$ is also the noise power in the $k^{th}$ bin, so it can't be zero unless there is no noise at all in that bin.

Comment: Thank you very much... That makes sense now. ... Many thanks again

Comment: Indeed that was very helpful :

Comment: I am reviewing my MMSE code, and I just to make sure that I am using the variance function correctly. From the above comments, I assumed that E{|Dk|2} = |Dk|2  and in matlab, it is just (abs(Dk))^2 . Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mona: No, $E\{|D_k|^2\}$ is the *average* noise power, which needs to be estimated. To keep things simple, you could assume that your input data contain a segment with only noise from which you can obtain an estimate of $E\{|D_k|^2\}$ by averaging $|D_k|^2$ over all noise frames. Obviously, this assumes that the noise is stationary, i.e. its characteristics don't change over time. In a more realistic setting you would use a noise tracking algorithm such as [this one](http://prb.tudelft.nl/sites/default/files/0004266.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I just read the abstract of the paper and browsed over its algorithm. It seems clear, but I must admit I am new to this. I am sure if I implement any additional thing on this project, my professor will give me bonus. However, let me go through Malah’s paper first. Yes, I agree, we are keeping things simple; i.e. taking white noise and adding it to the original speech and then doing reconstruction according to Malah’s algorithm. So, E{|Dk|2} is the difference between the kth element and the average noise of a particular frame?

Comment: @Mona: That's what I meant by 'keep things simple' in my previous comment. For your project you're probably not expected to implement a noise tracker. $E\{|D_k|^2\}$ is the average noise power, it's no difference etc., it's just the expected power of the noise in the $k^{th}$ frequency bin. You can estimate it by finding in your input signal a stretch of noise without desired signal (such as in a speech pause), and estimate the noise power by averaging the squared magnitudes of the signal (per frequency component) over all noise frames.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Yes I will update my code, in fact, the way I was calculating it was wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: The professor gave us formula for λd (n,k) = α λd(n-1,k) + (1-α) |D(n,k)|2

Comment: @Mona: OK, that's a recursive averaging. The question is just how to know that there's no desired signal in the input while you apply that formula. If you choose $\alpha$ very close to $1$, then you're probably on the safe side, in the sense that (non-stationary) speech doesn't affect the average too much.

Comment: yes, what you explained made more sense (to me at least) than using the formula that he gave us. Anyway, I am using α to 0.98. Anyway, thank you very much for the clear explanation.